# jQuery occasionally unavailable when loaded with 'defer' from CDN

Tags: jquery, dependencies, cdn, deferred-loading

I am experiencing a very sporadic problem with jQuery when loaded from a CDN with the `defer` attribute in Firefox:

```
<script defer src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" ></script>
<script defer src="http://localhost/bloomingtontutors/public/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.js" ></script>
<script defer src="http://localhost/bloomingtontutors/public/js/fuelux.js" ></script>
...
```

Most of the time, at least on my dev server, this works just fine.  However, perhaps 1 in 5 times when I load the page I get errors from Bootstrap, FuelUX, and just about every other plugin stating that jQuery is not defined:

[image: Failure to find jQuery]

I am surprised because even in this case, if I look at the timestamps in the Firefox console, it appears that the scripts are being loaded in the correct order.

What is going on here?  Is this a problem with `defer`, or with Firefox, or the CDN, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any specific reason of adding defer in jQuery?

Is its not dependent, you can try removing defer from it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" ></script>
<script defer src="http://localhost/bloomingtontutors/public/js/bootstrap-3.3.2.js" ></script>
<script defer src="http://localhost/bloomingtontutors/public/js/fuelux.js" ></script>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  But, I was hoping to defer all JS to improve my page load times.  `defer` is supposed to run sequentially, so I still have no idea why this problem happens.